# GatsbyJS: escape generated HTML for JSON body

Tags: regex, webpack, escaping, gatsby

I need to upload my GatsbyJS generated HTML to an api that takes source code in the JSON post body (https://developers.hubspot.com/docs/methods/templates/post_templates), I would like to escape the " characters in the static HTML generated by gatsby (and the other things mentioned in https://www.thorntech.com/2012/07/4-things-you-must-do-when-putting-html-in-json/ later on). I tried to extend gatsby's webpack with the following in `gatsby-node.js`

```
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({
  stage,
  // rules,
  // loaders,
  plugins,
  actions,
}) => {
  actions.setWebpackConfig({
    module: {
      rules:
        stage === 'build' || stage === 'build-html'
          ? [
              {
                test: /\.html$/,
                loader: 'string-replace-loader',
                options: {
                  search: '"',
                  replace: '\"',
                  flags: 'g',
                },
              },
            ]
          : [],
    },
  });
};
```

which uses this webpack loader https://www.npmjs.com/package/string-replace-loader. This doesn't work at all. However if I change the test to `/\.js$/` I can get 'string-replace-loader' to replace text inside js files. My `test: /\.html$/` is possibly looking for html files before they are generated?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like gatsby is not rendering [html directly with webpack](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/2b1b5516b40260014c795666548c095567e71183/packages/gatsby/src/commands/build-html.js#L44), so the webpack loader you use wouldn't work.

Instead, you could hook into the `onPostBuild` hook in `gatsby-node.js`, this will runs when htmls are generated. Then, you can use something like `glob` (webpack dependency) to find all html and escape them.

Here's a quick example, with the help of `fs-extra` (gatsby dependency):

```
const fs = require('fs-extra')
const glob = require('glob')

exports.onPostBuild = async () => {
  const htmls = glob.sync('./public/**/*.html') // array of paths to any htmls in public

  const escapeHtmls = htmls.map(async htmlPath => {
    const content = await fs.readFile(htmlPath, 'utf-8')

    const escaped = JSON.stringify(content)

    // upload the escaped strings to your api,
    // or write it to a local file with write file i.e `fs.writeFile(htmlPath, escaped)`

    console.log(`${htmlPath} has been escaped.`)
  })

  return Promise.all(escapeHtmls).catch(e => console.log(e))
}
```